# Delete and Insert performance SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, performance, linked-server, query-performance

I have the below stored procedure that is taking close to an hour to complete. The result set is about 200K machines.

All I am doing is extracting a set of ids from a linked server, deleting those ids in a local server and then extracting all details for those ids from a remote server and inserting them. The INSERT takes 90%, DELETE table 9% and SELECT INTO 1%.

id is the Primary Key/Clustered Index.

```
    DECLARE @ProcessDate DATETIME
    SET @ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, -3,
                                                    GETDATE()), 111)

    SELECT  DISTINCT id
    INTO    #temp_machines
    FROM    remote_server.db.dbo.table1
    WHERE   dt_modify >= @ProcessDate

    DELETE  FROM local_server.db.dbo.table2
    WHERE   id IN ( SELECT id  FROM  #temp_machines )

    INSERT  INTO local_server.db.dbo.table2
    SELECT  *
    FROM    remote_server.db.dbo.table1
    WHERE   id IN ( SELECT id  FROM  #temp_machines )
```

Any suggestions on improving performance?

Comment: Well put a clustered primary key on the temp table would be the first thing I’d try. Also try to figure out where the time is being spent. Is it the select into? The delete? The insert? You have three different queries but it is easy to determine which of them is/are the problem.

Comment: as far as I can tell all you are doing is `update t2
set t2.A=t1.A, t2.B=t1.B, etc.
from
local_server.db.dbo.table2 as t2 inner join
remote_server.db.dbo.table1 as t1 
on t2.id=t1.id WHERE   dt_modify >= @ProcessDate
`

Answer (score 5):

**First step:** Make sure there's something to tune and that your query isn't just being blocked. You can do this with free tools like [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/) or [sp_BlitzFirst](http://firstresponderkit.org) (disclaimer, I'm a contributor to the First Responder Kit).

**Second step:** Don't use [local variables](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options).

**Third step:** Maybe [indexing the temp table](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/12/indexing-temp-tables/) will help.

**Fourth step:** [Check your wait stats](http://firstresponderkit.org) using sp_BlitzFirst (same disclaimer about me contributing to it, blah blah blah). It could be that the query as written is fine, but you're running into some other issue, like tempdb contention.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that by "remote server" you mean a linked server (or something similar, at least), then one potential issue is that you're making two queries for what amounts to the same data. Also, by using `IN (SELECT ...)`, you may be forcing the server to re-run that `SELECT` statement once per row.

I'd try something like the following:

```
DECLARE @ProcessDate DATETIME
SET @ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, -3,
                                                GETDATE()), 111)

SELECT  *
INTO    #temp_machines
FROM    table1
WHERE   dt_modify >= @ProcessDate

DELETE  t2
FROM    table2 t2
          INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM #temp_machines) tm ON (t2.id = tm.id)

INSERT  INTO table2
SELECT  *
FROM    #temp_machines
```

After all, you're going to pull all the matching data from `table1` into your local DB at some point; get it up front, and you can ignore the remote server for the rest of the query.

Even better, if `table1.id` is unique, or a primary key, your `DELETE` can be:

```
DELETE  t2
FROM    table2 t2
          INNER JOIN #temp_machines tm ON (t2.id = tm.id)
```

It's possible that this would work even if there are multiple instances of certain id values in `table1`.

Answer (score 1):

While it doesn't show in your query syntax (anonymized, natch) your question implies that `table1` is on a remote server. You're probably addressing it in real life with four-part syntax, right?

`[RemoteServerAlias].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName]`

When you update that remote table SQL has an interesting time trying to optimize the problem. Because it doesn't have all the information it needs it sometimes makes very questionable decisions. The last query there is almost certainly bringing the entire contents of the remote table over from that server before trying to filter it.

If your initial query is fast enough -- that is, if SQL is applying that date criterion -- I'd suggest a workaround. Add that criterion to the end.

```
INSERT  INTO table2
SELECT  *
FROM    table1
WHERE   id IN ( SELECT id  FROM  #temp_machines )
AND     dt_modify >= @ProcessDate
```